# Why does my text div spill out past my container div?

Tags: html, css

I really need your help,

I can't seem to figure out as to why my div #text spills out past my container div? It should fit nicely inside its container?

Here is the CSS markup:

```
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#container {
    background: #FFF;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100,139,170);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(100,139,170);
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#text {

    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="container">

        <div style="float:left;" class="topbar">Custom Dialog Box</div><div class="topbar" style="text-align: right;">Close</div>

        <div id="text"><p>test</p></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here is a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Your CSS code is cut off at the beginning.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6zgjugq/ Should give you some clues.

Comment: Should be considered as answer :)

Comment: @odedta - Not really, it's not fixed to the center the way the OP probably imagines.  But it does show the flaws in the above approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#test {height:100%;}` it will look for it's parent's height, all the way to `#wrapper` which is set to `height:100px`, so `#test` will get the same height, plus the borders, and the `#container` doesn't have enough space to hold it (due to the extra blue bar), so it overflows.

I also noticed the layout can be done simpler as follows.

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -50px; /*half height*/
    margin-right: -250px; /*half width*/
    position: absolute;
    /* display: none; */
}
#container {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100, 139, 170);
}
.topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(100, 139, 170);
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#text {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div style="float:left;" class="topbar">Custom Dialog Box</div>
        <div class="topbar" style="text-align: right;">Close</div>
        <div id="text">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The height of `#text` is `100%` which means it gets the height of the containing block, in this case `#container`. Both the height of `#text` as well as the `#container` are `500px`. But #text is being pushed down by it's sibling `.topbar`, causing it to overflow.

To solve this you can use the css property `overflow:auto` as suggested by [Jarred Farrish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish) in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the height of the `#container` but remember that there is also sort of a header at the top of the container so the text `height` should be < 100% because you have to substract the `height` of the dialog header.

Answer (score 0):

Amir got point, the way you can "fix" this is to add padding to content, so you got safe space.

[CodePen Sample](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/ZGYbdr)

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="container">

    <div style="float:left;" class="topbar">Custom Dialog Box</div><div class="topbar" style="text-align: right;">Close</div>

    <div id="text"><p>test</p></div>

</div>
```

```
#wrapper{
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#container {
    background: #FFF;
    left: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    top: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100,139,170);
    position: relative;
}
.topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(100,139,170);
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#text {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I also fixed positioning for you.